# QFT with fixed boundary conditions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, boundary-conditions

I am looking for references on the formulation of QFTs with fixed boundary conditions for the fields (typically $\phi(0)=\phi(L)=0$), and especially how to construct the corresponding perturbative expansion (propagators, Feynman diagrams, etc.).

I'm used to the periodic boundary conditions (especially in the context of condensed matter, due to finite temperature), and the use of Matsubara frequencies, and I'm wondering what is different in this case. 
Note that the free propagator is not sufficient for what I need, I would like to also have more informations on the properties of the full vertex functions, etc.

It seems that CFTs deal with this kind of things, but I am very unfamiliar with these methods, and I would rather deal with a more standard QFT textbook.

Comment: You could try the heat kernel literature and the Casimir literature.  There is this review of the heat kernel: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306138.

Comment: @user2309840: that's a good point. If you have a nice reference for the Casimir effect, I would love to have it.

Comment: I don't, unfortunately.